# Ordering multiple lists at once with one as base reference

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am using `sklearn` to calculate some eigenvalues and eigenvectors, part of my problem is that I want to order the eigenvalues, calculate a cumulative sum over them and compare that number to a certain variance threshold. As soon as I know for example the first 3 eigenvalues are sufficient and will get me past that threshold, I will have to find the corresponding eigenvectors.

Like this

```
base_list = [2,3,1,4]
sorted_base_list = sorted(base_list, reverse=True)
>>> [4,3,2,1]
second_list = [[3,3][1,1][4,4][2,2]]
```

Applying the re-ordering of `base_list` to `second_list` I would like to get this

```
second_list = [[2,2][1,1][3,3][4,4]]
```

In other words I want to have my eigenvector list of lists ordered in the same way as my eigenvalues.

any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at the `second_list` output, can you please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating under the assumption that your base list and second list will always be the same length, here's how I would do it (without using another library like numpy).

If you turn the second list into a list of tuples where the first element of the tuple is the corresponding element in base list, you could sort the second list the way that you want.

```
for i in range(len(second_list)):
    second_list[i] = (base_list[i], second_list[i])
```

Now you can sort the second list the same way as the base list:

```
sorted_second_list = sorted(second_list, reverse=True)
```

You could then extract the values from the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.argsort(base_list)[::-1]
s_list = [second_list[i] for i in indices]
print(s_list)
#[[2, 2], [1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
#Note: your second list is missing commas between lists.
```

If you don't want to use numpy

```
indices = sorted(range(len(base_list)), key=base_list.__getitem__, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map your unsorted eigenvalues to values of base list. Then sort your base list and then create a list of sorted eigenvalues by using the sorted list as indices:

```
base_list = [2, 3,1,4]
second_list =[[3,3],[1,1],[4,4],[2,2]]
eigen_map = {i: eigenvalue for i, eigenvalue in zip(base_list, second_list)}
sorted_list = sorted(base_list)
sorted_eigenvalues = [eigen_map[index] for index in sorted_list]
```

This gives:
    [[4, 4], [3, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]]